# Adding an image to the ylabel in pyplot

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot, label

I would like to set an image as the ylabel for a plot I've made.

The following code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data

from matplotlib.offsetbox import (TextArea, DrawingArea, OffsetImage,
                                  AnnotationBbox)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[1,4,2,8,5,7,1])

arr = np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10))
im = OffsetImage(arr, zoom=2)
im.image.axes = ax
xy = (1, 5)

ab = AnnotationBbox(im, xy)

ax.add_artist(ab)

plt.show()
```

generates the following figure:

[image]

I would like that picture to be to the left of the yaxis ticks, rather than on the plot.

I've tried changing the line `xy = (1, 5)`, but that just makes the image disappear.

I've also tried writing `ax.set_ylabel(ab)` and `ax.set_ylabel(im)`, though (predictably) these just put the name of the object as the y-axis label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not want to position your ylabel in terms of data coordinates as this would change the ylabel as soon as you plot different data or zoom into the plot.

Instead position it in axes coordinates. Those range from 0 to 1 in both axes directions, such that the y label would probably best sit at some slightly negative x position (outside the axes) and in the middle of it in terms of y position.

```
AnnotationBbox(im, (-0.1, 0.5) , xycoords='axes fraction')
```

Complete example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[1,4,2,8,5,7,1])

arr = np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10))
im = OffsetImage(arr, zoom=2)
im.image.axes = ax
xy = (-0.1,0.5 )

ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (-0.1, 0.5), xycoords='axes fraction')

ax.add_artist(ab)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I get the impression that this is lowering the resolution of my images, though perhaps there's no way around that

Comment: It should not change the resolution. This is essentially set via `zoom=2`. If this is a problem, could you show two images, one with and one without this change applied?

Comment: You're right - I just tried again, and the problem only appears in my GUI. There must be a larger problem with my code. Thanks for all your help